# Multiple @SpringBootApplication Annotation in a Project

Tags: spring-boot

In my project created by SpringBoot,

I have added 2 main classes with @SpringBootApplication.

Because if I use STS I can choose one main application when start to debug.

But I found that while SpringDemoApplication is up ,RabbitMQApplication is  also running.

Is this specification ? working appropriately?

Here this is sample to reproduce 
https://github.com/MariMurotani/SpringDemo/tree/6_rabbitMQ

[image]

**SpringDemoApplication**

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(SpringDemoApplication.class);
        ApplicationContext context = application.run(args);

    }
}
```

**RabbitMQApplication**

```
package demo;

import java.util.Date;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import demo.configs.Const;
import demo.dto.Mail;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RabbitMQApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;


@Autowired
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(Const.RabbitMQMessageQue, false);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("spring-boot-exchange");
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(Const.RabbitMQMessageQue);
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(Const.RabbitMQMessageQue);
    //container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}

/*
For asyncronized receiving

@Bean
Receiver receiver() {
    return new Receiver();
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
}*/

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SpringApplication.run(RabbitMQApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Waiting five seconds...");

    while(0 < 1){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
            String object = (String)rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(Const.RabbitMQMessageQue);
            if(object != null){
                try{
                    System.out.println(new Date().toGMTString() + ": " + object);
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    Mail mail = mapper.readValue(object, Mail.class);
                    System.out.println(mail.getToAddress() + " , " + mail.getStrContent());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is a shortcut annotation for `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan`.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

The default behavior of `@ComponentScan` is to look for `@Configuration` and `@Component` classes within the same package and all sub-packages of the annotated class. Since all your classes are in the same package, when you start any one of them Spring will find the others and treat them like `@Configuration` classes, and register their beans, etc.

So yes, this is expected behavior given your project setup. Put each `@SpringBootApplication` class in a separate subpackage if you don't want this to happen for local testing. If this moves beyond a demo at some point you'll probably want to come up with a better setup (subprojects for each `@SpringBootApplication` perhaps).

Comment: I have 3 kinds of scripts which i want to run as periodic jobs. How do i structure them in the same project so that i can run one independently at a time?

Comment: @Adi You may want to ask that as a standalone question, but you could essentially do what this answer recommends and have multiple classes with `main` methods and then specify the class name at run-time, or you could pass in an argument to a single `main` method to tell it which script to run.

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced the same scenario here and I solved with a simple solution.

My project uses Maven and is configured with sub-modules like this:

```
my-parent
  |__ my-main (depends on my-other module)
  |__ my-other
```

Each module has its own main App class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. The problem is that both classes reside in the same package even though they are in different modules.

Once I start `MyMainApp` it also starts `MyOtherApp`. To avoid this, I just had to do the following.

In the my-main module I have:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyMainApp ... { ... }
```

and  in the my-other module I have:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.other.active", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class MyOtherApp ... { ... }
```

with application.properties with:

```
my.other.active=true
```

It works as expected.

Comment: Hey danieldestro, I tried your method and it works as expected, but then when I run a unit test for the app , the application is not loaded if @ConditionalOnProperty annotation is added