# Spring does not run job from another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, jobs

I have a scheduling module in my spring boot project, in that project there is a job that runs normally when I test the scheduling module.

I need to use this module inside another one, so I imported it in the target module's **build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':scheduling')
```

I also added in the target module the job execution settings in the `bootstrap.yml` file

```
schedule:
  account:
    unblock:
      process-time: "0 0/1 * * * ?"
      thread-pool:
        name-prefix: schedule-job-executor
        core-pool-size: 1
        max-pool-size: 2
        queue-capacity: 1
        use-max-available-processors: false
      query:
        limit-size: 100
        execution-count: 3
        execute-until-end: true
```

This is the main class of the target module, I added the annotations for running and configuring the job.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({EventsConfig.class, SchedulingConfig.class})
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ScheduleQueryProperties.class, ScheduleThreadPoolProperties.class,
        ScheduleUnblockMaintenceLimitQueryProperties.class, ScheduleUnblockMaintenceLimitThreadPool.class})
public class EventsStarter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventsStarter.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        try {
            SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        SpringApplication.run(EventsStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the main class of the source module

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Import({SchedulingConfig.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ScheduleQueryProperties.class, ScheduleThreadPoolProperties.class,
        ScheduleUnblockMaintenceLimitQueryProperties.class, ScheduleUnblockMaintenceLimitThreadPool.class})
public class SchedulingStarter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulingStarter.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        try {
            SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulingStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

Debugging the target application, the application runs without errors but the job does not run

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64557368/175554 may help also having 2 SpringBootApplication is not a good practice. better to have one app class and make sure app starts the scheduler.